# Cron job - Codeigniter - Class 'CI_Controller' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I'm trying to create a cron job on cpanel using this command:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/mystuff/public_html/application/controllers/scripts.php scripts release_reviews
```

My scripts.php controller is as follows:

```
<?php

class Scripts extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) show_error('Direct access is not allowed');

    }

    public function release_reviews()
    {
        echo release_reviews(); //where the actual logic will sit once the cron job works
    }
}
```

The feedback I get when I try to run the cron job:
**Fatal error**:  Class 'CI_Controller' not found in **/home/mystuff/public_html/application/controllers/scripts.php** on line **3**

I can't find any evidence anyone has the same problem as me - most topics around this do the same as me and it works just fine apparently.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4):

To access CodeIgnter via the command line, you want to call the `index.php` file, not your controller.

```
php /home/mystuff/public_html/index.php scripts release_reviews
```

Docs: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Comment: I have tried exactly that but it now says "404 Page Not Found". The index.php is however definitely located where I stated.

Comment: I was actually just trying that as well - the cron job just doesn't run anymore if I add "local". So that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: @Davor: I'm not sure what to tell ya.  Is CodeIgniter configured fully?

Comment: Well I have a fully working website so CI is configured fully (at least CI_Controller or MY_Controller are working in the application). Thx for your help, hopefully a miracle happens and the solutions pops up at some point!

Comment: What CI version are you using?  CLI was kinda flaky in the 1.7.x series.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `CI_Controller` class. `CRON` jobs only load that file, so it can't find any `CI_Controller`. You are going to have to include the `CI_CONTROLLER` class before the class definition

Something like this

```
<?php

require_once('path_to_CI_controller');

class Scripts extends CI_Controller
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the following in the routes file and it worked!
I figured this out. My newbie problem is that the arguments need to be configured.

e.g.

```
`$route['pdfscript/runmethod']  = "batch/pdfscript/runmethod";
$route['pdfscript/runmethod/(:any)'] = "batch/pdfscript/runmethod/$1";'

`pdfscript.php
<?php 
class pdfscript extends CI_Controller {
public function runmethod($file) {
echo $file;
.....`
```

**cmd line>** php.exe index.php pdfscript runmethod filename